# Antonym of "assume" or; a synonym of "assume" and its antonym

Tags: verbs, synonyms, antonyms, modal-verbs, present-tense

As the title implies, I am looking for a good, simple, single word antonym of "assume".  Alternatively, if no good antonym exists that satisfies the requirements below, I am also open to suggestions for a synonym of "assume" and its antonym.

EDIT: the definition of "assume" here is that of "belief".

The specific context is as a function name in a programming language, where the user can, for instance, `assume X is zero`.  The antonym must follow the same pattern, i. e., `_ X is zero` and ideally be an "obvious" partner, i. e., when reading it should be clear to most people that it undoes the assumption.

EDIT: this is for symbolic manipulation, not a variable binding.  Assuming `X is zero` is a *very* different concept from binding `X` to a value that is zero—the latter is a much stronger assumption.  This is also not an assertion, i. e., checking whether the assumption holds.  In all the cases I have encountered in the literature, the antonym is either always implicit, or negated by use of something akin to "if we no longer assume X".

I looked in a thesaurus, and the only good candidate I could find was "forget".  The problem with this word is that I don't think it is immediately clear that it undoes an assumption, and I would struggle to remember it (ironically).  Another word that I have considered is, "unassume".  It is not in any dictionary, but I think it is fairly obvious from the context what it *means*, and I find it memorable.

Comment: "Unassume" may not be in any dictionary, but "unassuming" is - and it has a quite different meaning. Could you not negate the assumption by `assume X is not zero` or `do not assume that x is zero`?

Comment: `assume X is not zero` has a very different meaning since it is an assumption about `X`.  `do not assume X is zero` works, but is not a single word, so it doesn't read so well if you contract it, i. e., in the programming language it will become `@donotassume iszero(X)` or `@do_not_assume iszero(X)`, which is why I am mostly after a single word antonym.

Comment: When I first read your question title, I thought of “doubt”, as in “I doubted that it would rain, so I didn’t bring my umbrella.”   But, given then context, I would suggest `deny`.   Actually, “deny” may be antonyms with “assert”, but the programming paradigm that you are talking about ***is*** often called `assert`.

Comment: I like "doubt", actually!  `deny` is a bit strong for my taste, and this is also different from an assertion.  An assertion will error if the assumption is incorrect.  Rather, this is part of an optimization step before the exact value of `X` is know, but some assumptions about its properties can still be made.  For instance, if we `assume x is zero`, then `x + y` can be reduced to `y`.

Comment: If you're going to coin a term, then `disassume` has exactly 1 Google result, and `nonassume` has 2 (relevant ones).

Comment: Given that you like *doubt* as its opposite, does this mean that you are defining *assume* to mean "believe" (or, more specifically, "hold as an opinion on faith")? You haven't yet said what you understand the meaning of *assume* to be.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry, I forgot "assume" could mean something other than "belief", and assumed it had only the meaning I was thinking of.

Comment: @jsw29 This is not a question about programming.  This is a question about finding English words with the meanings that I am after.

Comment: Because you are using this in a very technical context (variable binding, proving properties of programs) you may want to ask this at a technical site where there would be more subject matter expertise (and where the culture may have a specific answer). For example, math.SE or one of the programming.SE sites. Also, 'Do not assume...' is probably the phrasing that captures the concept the most accurately; don't be a slave to single words per concept.

Comment: As a programmer, I'm unclear exactly what "assume" and it's opposite are supposed to do.  Could you clarify? As you said, "don't assume x" is not the same as "assume not x"

Comment: Finding an antonym presupposes a metric. If we take certainty as our metric, with ‘assumptions’ being characterised by uncertainty (if you were certain, you wouldn’t call it an assumption), then *know* can count as an antonym. The later part of your question makes it clear this isn’t what you’re looking for, though, so I’ll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: The OP seems to agree that *do not assume* would work well in writing and speaking; the only reason for rejecting it is that it wouldn't work well when transposed into a programming language. This is what leaves an impression that the question is about programming and not about English language.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks.  I actually asked this on a technical site and it was suggested to me that I post it here, so that is why I did it.  The more I think about it, the more I also like "do not assume".

Comment: Symbol manipulation systems like _Mathematica_ have been around for decades. Unless you’re attempting to design around a patented feature, just use what already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *assume* in the sense that you are is the equivalent of its fourth sense from [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assume):

> **4** : to take as granted or true : SUPPOSE
> // I *assume* he'll be there.

In other words, you simply accept something as fact. Even if you don't necessarily believe it to be true, you act as if it were true.

---

While *forget* is an interesting candidate for its opposite, I don't think it's as accurate as something else.

When you *assume* something, you are accepting it *without* ***question***.

Therefore, it seems reasonable that [**question**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/question) would be the antonym:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : to ask a question of or about
> **2** : to interrogate intensively : CROSS-EXAMINE
> **3a** : DOUBT, DISPUTE
> **b** : to subject to analysis : EXAMINE

So, you might say something like the following:

> On the contrary! Rather than *assume* those facts, I urge you to *question* them.

Or:

> I *question* the truth of his statement.

Or in your specific case:

> I *question* if X is actually zero.

Depending on the specific context and your intent, a synonym of *question* (the words in capitals in the definition) could also be used.

Answer (score 2):

What about *discount*? You would have to change the "is" to "being":

> discount X being zero

The **Cambridge Dictionary** defines the verb "discount" as:

> to decide that something or someone is not worth considering or giving attention

I do wonder if it's strong enough to act as a true antonym of "assume" in this context, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **set** and **unset**, which have been used in *Mathematica* for the past 25 years.

In a programming language, a statement that changes the value of a variable is only meaningful if the variable is referenced at a later point in the program. In some languages, though, a symbolic expression *in the language itself*  can be manipulated, e.g. differentiated with respect to its unbound variables. In such cases, the “setting” or “unsetting” of a variable alters the type of action that can be performed on the expression at a later stage.

Please think twice before you introduce a new word for an already familiar operation. I realize that existing languages are protected by patents and copyrights, and that some words may be legally unusable, but binding and unbinding are very basic concepts.

**Edited to add:**

@dalum Look at it this way:  in a symbolic reasoning system, you can have an assertion that limits the range of values that can be assigned to a free variable. This corresponds only in part to the human action of *assuming*, but in the execution of the program there is no assumption, simply recording and calculation.  One set of symbolic statements can be transformed into a different set, from which a different form of information can be obtained.

In the case you describe, you are removing an assertion about the free variable from your set of statements. However, there may be many assertions in the set, so it may not be possible to say anything at the higher semantic level about “disassuming”. There may be other assertions that implicity restrict the range of the free variable.

Also, don’t go by what you read in the literature in the words surrounding equations. Natural language and symbolic reasoning are different, and a lot of mathematics is closer to natural language than you might think. Otherwise, the [Principia Mathematica](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) would not have taken as long to write, or be as difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think you have misunderstood what I am doing.  The specific operation that this does is not a binding of a variable, but rather an assumption about its properties which can be propagated.  For instance, one can assume that a variable `X` is greater than `5` without actually binding it.  This is in other languages/packages called `assuming` and is in, for instance Maple, written in postfix notation to apply to a single statement.  The word `assume` is also used widely for this in the physics and mathematics literature, but I have never encountered its antonym.

Comment: Just read your edited notes, and I really appreciate it.  I thought about your suggestion some more, and I think you may be right that `set` and `unset` could be used in this context instead of `assume`/(`forget`/`question`/`unassume`).